# How to do multipart batching http requests?

Tags: c#, http

I have this code which does a basic post request

```
public static async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string token_type, string access_token, string postData, string accept, string content_type, ErrorList errors)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, content_type) // CONTENT-TYPE header
    };
    if (accept != null) request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
    if (token_type != null && access_token != null) request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token_type, access_token);
    HttpResponseMessage g = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (g.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        errors.AddError(g.ReasonPhrase, await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to multipart/batching as shown here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/batchingrequests

Here is the example from the site:

```
POST https://lyncweb.contoso.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/103/batch HTTP/1.1
Accept: multipart/batching
Content-Type: multipart/batching;boundary=77f2569d-c005-442b-b856-782305305e5f
Authorization: Bearer cwt=AAEB...buHc
X-Ms-Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://lyncweb.contoso.com/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFra/documentation/Resources-me
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: lyncweb.contoso.com
Content-Length: 463
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

--77f2569d-c005-442b-b856-782305305e5f
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/103/people/contacts HTTP/1.1
Host: lyncweb.contoso.com
Accept: application/json

--77f2569d-c005-442b-b856-782305305e5f
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/103/me HTTP/1.1
Host: lyncweb.contoso.com
Accept: application/json

--77f2569d-c005-442b-b856-782305305e5f--
```

How can I make an equivalent c# request using the technique as in my Post example?